# What happen if we do operations on mocked objects? Rspec

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, rspec

Firsty I would say that I'm learning Ruby and TDD program, so please be forgiving for me. Acctualy I have two questions releted with each other but firsty please take a look on this code. Its part of my unit test for class Order:

```
  context 'with products' do
      let(:result) { instance_double('Money', value: 20, currency: 'EUR') }
      let(:xxx) { instance_double('Money', value: 10, currency: 'EUR') }
      let(:money2) { instance_double('Money', value: 10, currency: 'EUR',:+ => xxx , :to_s => '10.00 EUR' ) }
      let(:money) { instance_double('Money', value: 10, currency: 'EUR', :+ => money2, :to_s => '10.00 EUR') }
      let(:product1) { instance_double('Product', price: money2) }
      let(:product2) { instance_double('Product', price: money) }
      let(:products) { [product1, product2] }

      it 'returns sum of product prices' do
    #Real objects    
    product1 = Product.new
    product1.price = Money.new('1.23', 'EUR')
    product1.name = product1
    product2 = Product.new
    product2.price = Money.new('1.23', 'EUR')
    product2.name = product2
    products1 = [product1,product2]
    puts products1.map!(&:price)

    #Fake
    puts "fakeproducts map"
    fakeproducts = products.map!(&:price)
    puts fakeproducts
    puts "Sum of fakeproducts"
    puts Money.sum(fakeproducts)
    puts Money.sum(fakeproducts).to_s
    puts "methods of sum fakeproducts"
    puts Money.sum(fakeproducts).methods

    expect(Order.new(full_name, date, products).total_amount).to eql result
  end
end
```

Problem is that my real objects works,but mocked objects doens't . Error which I got:

```
Failure/Error: expect(Order.new(full_name, date, products).total_amount).to eql result
       Double "Money (instance)" received unexpected message :price with (no args)
```

Total_amount function:

```
 def total_amount 
   return 0 if products.empty?
   asd = products.map!(&:price)
   Money.sum(asd)
 end
```

and Money.sum looks like this:

```
 def self.sum(moneys)
    moneys.group_by(&:currency).values.map(&:sum)
 end
```

I suspect that, when I do some operations on my mocked object it lose its properties.
The questions are:

1. Is it normal that this things happen?
2. What is Solutions for this problem? Should I mock result of my function?

Answer (score 1):

Your use of `map!` in `total_amount` is clobbering the `products` associated with the order, replacing them with their price, so that the next time you call `price` on the order's products (e.g. as in a subsequent call to `total_amount`), you are sending `price` to one of your money doubles.

You can avoid this particular symptom by using `map` instead of `map!` inside of `total_amount`.

As a related side, it's much easier to provide help with these kinds of questions if you provide the stack trace with your error and identify the corresponding source lines in your code.